# How to run TestNG test nodes in sequence but all inside classes in parallel for different browser capabilities?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, saucelabs, browserstack

I want to run my automation suite (implemented using Selenium Webdriver (Java) + TestNG + Maven) in parallel against multiple browser capabilities. I can run it in parallel for different capabilities using below sample testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" name="Functional Test Suite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Windows-FF-37.0" preserve-order="true" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
        <parameter name="version" value="37.0"/>
        <parameter name="os" value="Windows"/>
        <parameter name="os_version" value="8.1"/>
        <parameter name="device" value=""/>
        <classes>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FirstTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.SecondTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.ThirdTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FourthTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="MAC-Yosemite-Chrome-36.0" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <parameter name="version" value="36.0"/>
        <parameter name="os" value="OS X"/>
        <parameter name="os_version" value="Yosemite"/>
        <parameter name="device" value=""/>
        <classes>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FirstTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.SecondTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.ThirdTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FourthTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

But when I run this testng.xml, it starts with 'FirstTest' on both VMs; one with Chrome+Mac & another with Forefox+Windows configuration. I DO NOT want this, because the data modified by one script fails another script.

My requirement is to run all classes from one  node in parallel and  nodes in sequence.
As a work around, I can always put classes name in different order in different test nodes, but since I am having hundreds of test classes, it is not feasible solution.

Also, eventually I want to set up these parameters through some properties file so that I can manage the run environments easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below steps:

- Define 2 different suites (XML files) for different tests.
- for each suite mention: `thread-count="4" parallel="classes"`
- Create a third suite (xml file) to run the above 2 files sequentially (Don't mention thread-count & parallel parameters for suite.)

**First XML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" name="Functional Test Suite1" parallel="classes">
    <test name="Windows-FF-37.0" preserve-order="true" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
        <parameter name="version" value="37.0"/>
        <parameter name="os" value="Windows"/>
        <parameter name="os_version" value="8.1"/>
        <parameter name="device" value=""/>
        <classes>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FirstTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.SecondTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.ThirdTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FourthTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Second XML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" name="Functional Test Suite2" parallel="classes">
    <test name="MAC-Yosemite-Chrome-36.0" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <parameter name="version" value="36.0"/>
        <parameter name="os" value="OS X"/>
        <parameter name="os_version" value="Yosemite"/>
        <parameter name="device" value=""/>
        <classes>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FirstTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.SecondTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.ThirdTest"/>
            <class name="uat.mycompany.tests.FourthTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Third XML file (Need to execute this file):**

```
<suite name="suite of suites">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="Functional Test Suite1.xml" />
        <suite-file path="Functional Test Suite2.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above example set `<suite thread-count="4" name="Functional Test Suite" parallel="classes">`

If you set `thread-count` to be less than the number of `classes` inside a `test` then `tests` will run sequentially but the `classes` will run in parallel. Once all the test `classes` are run in the `test` then next `test` will start.

Comment: Hi 9ikhan, I tried in multiple ways by using your suggestion, but every time it starts just single thread. set thread-count="4" parallel = "classes", but this did not help. I tried this before as well. Please let me know if you have any other solution in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
<test name="api test" parallel="methods">

    <groups>

        <run>
            <include name="test_proxy" />
        </run>

    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class name="com.spire.test.TestAutomation" />
    </classes>

</test>

<test name="api test1" parallel="methods">

    <groups>

        <run>
            <include name="test" />
        </run>

    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class name="com.spire.test1.TestAutomation1" />
    </classes>

</test>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can code like below, it will work.